# Server Socket Keeps Reading Data Until I close Socket from Client In Java

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, outputstream

Im unable to get data in server from client using java
Following is my server code :

```
 public void UpdateClients() throws Exception{

    Socket socktmp=null;

    try
    {
        socktmp= mainSocket.accept();
        rdr= new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(socktmp.getInputStream()));
        String t="";
        String name="";
        while((t=rdr.readLine())!=null){     <<<<< **it stops here**
            name=t;
        }
        //rdr.close();
        LstClient.AddClient(name, socktmp);

        objwriter = new ObjectOutputStream(socktmp.getOutputStream());
        objwriter.writeObject(LstClient.clients);
        objwriter.flush();  
        objwriter.close();
   }
   catch(Exception ex){
        throw new Exception("Unable to Update Clients. Error :" + ex.getMessage());
   }
      finally{
        try{
            if(mainSocket!=null){
                mainSocket.close();
            }
            if(socktmp!=null){
                socktmp.close();
            }
            if(rdr!=null)
            {
                rdr.close();
            }
            if(objwriter!=null)
            {
                objwriter.close();
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex1){
            throw new Exception("Unable to close streams after opeining. Error :"+ ex1.getMessage());
        }


   }


}
```

and following is my client code:

```
public Client(String serverIp,int port,String name) throws Exception{

    try{
        if(mainSock!=null){
        mainSock.close();
        }
        mainSock= new Socket(serverIp, port);
        writer= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(mainSock.getOutputStream()));

        writer.write(name);
        writer.flush();
        **//writer.close();**
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        objin = new ObjectInputStream(mainSock.getInputStream());
        Hashtable<String,Socket> lst= new Hashtable<String , Socket>();
        lst = (Hashtable<String, Socket>) objin.readObject();
        cl = new LstClient();
        LstClient.clients = lst;
        System.out.println(LstClient.clients.size());
        objin.close();

    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        throw new Exception("Error : "+ ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        if(mainSock!=null){
            mainSock.close();

        }
        if(writer!=null){
            writer.close();
        }
        if(objin!=null){
            objin.close();
        }


    }

}
```

I only get data in server or cursor goes on reading line on server side when i close writer in client end. but when i try to read after closing the writer at client end it says socket is closed so without closing it pauses on readline on server end
please help

Comment: Reading the input until end of stream and then trying to write output to the same socket doesn't make sense. End of stream on a socket usually means that the peer has closed the connection. You should probably just read a line at a time and respond to it, or whatever your application protocol really demands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I very common mistake when using readLine, is to forget to send a new line.

You are sending text without a new line i.e. `\n` but waiting for it to be sent all the same.

Try adding `write('\n');`

Answer (score 1):

Because you are reading with [`readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29), which will block until it runs into a carriage return. Add a '\n' at the end of your name. Or better yet, use a [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) and write using `println`

Comment: The down side of using PrintWriter is it swallows IOExceptions silently.

Comment: That's a pretty big downside actually. You can use checkError() but there's no feedback on what went wrong. Although most IOException on writes are resolved the same way from the client's perspective. Reconnect/retry

Comment: The solution is to use `BufferedWriter` and `BufferedWriter.newline().`